# Selecting random data with mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, nosql

I want to select random data with mongoose but I don't want to get the same data again.

Example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....n]

first select: [1,4,5] first $nin blank
second select: [2,8,6] second $nin: [1,4,5]
third select: [3,7] -- third $nin: [1,4,5,2,8,6]
```

$nin: [$n1,n2,n3........n]

I can't trust the operator of $nin. When I select to randomly choose between 10.000.000 data, I think I will experience performance problems.  Is this right way?  Is there a different alternative?

Comment: What you can do is create an array containing the possible random values, and then create a random within that array to get one of these values, after taking the value you remove that value obtained from the array to avoid getting it again

Comment: There is a $sample operator.